# full box border with missing part on title of box css only

Tags: html, css, border

I am making a project that has may div and every div i have a full box border to determine or see the boundary for each div i want to make it look cooler by adding a title to each box in the border itself i want to achieve something like this image below

[image: full box border]

the image below is the thing i want to achieve using css. i search for a way but so far none is working almost all is saying to use image with the design of this kind of border but i am trying to make it using `border-style` but i am not sure if this is even possible any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would use the fieldset html tag with a legend to achieve this,

here is the code:

```
<div>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Box title:</legend>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>foo</span>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

and here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/oogley_boogley/kzn2g2nh/2/

Answer (score 1):

you should use `<fieldset>` for that and you should change the fieldset css style to `display:block` for  styling otherwise it will act as an inline element.

[*documentation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cca425kL/)

```
legend{

    color:red;
}
fieldset{
    display:block;
    height:100px;
}
```